# Defining a Function programmatically

Tags: performance-tuning, meta-programming

I need to create a function programmatically.  For example, suppose I've got:

1. mon - a Symbol
2. mons - a List of Symbols
3. vars - another List of Symbols (same Length)

and want to make a function as:

```
Function[{«mon»},
 Function[«mons»,
  Internal`InheritedBlock[«vars»,
   «vars[[1]]» =.;
   «vars[[2]]» =.;
   ...
   «vars[[-1]]» =.;
   «vars[[1]]» = «mons[[1]]»;
   «vars[[2]]»[t] = «mons[[2]]»;
   ...
   «vars[[-1]]»[t] = «mons[[-1]]»;
   «mon»
]]]
```

where «» denotes injecting from the given mon, mons, and vars.

So the input

```
mon = Unique[NDSolve`Monitor];
mons = Table[Unique[mon], {3}];
vars = {t, x, y};
```

would result in the desired output:

```
Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$3080}, 
 Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$3080$3081, NDSolve`Monitor$3080$3082, NDSolve`Monitor$3080$3083},
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{t, x, y},
   t =.;
   x =.;
   y =.;
   t = NDSolve`Monitor$3080$3081;
   x[t] = NDSolve`Monitor$3080$3082; 
   y[t] = NDSolve`Monitor$3080$3083;
   NDSolve`Monitor$3080
]]]
```

One possible solution involves building up a `String`, then using `ToExpression`:

```
str = "Function[{" <> ToString[mon] <> "},
  Function[" <> ToString[mons] <> ",
  Internal`InheritedBlock[" <> ToString[vars] <> ",
";
Do[
  str = str <> ToString[var] <> "=.;\n"
, {var, vars}];
str = str <> "t=" <> ToString[mons[[1]]] <> ";\n";
Do[
  str = str <> ToString[vars[[i]]] <> "[t]=" <> ToString[mons[[i]]] <> ";\n"
, {i, 2, Length[vars]}];
str = str <> ToString[mon] <> "]]]\n";
```

but this is kind of inelegant and can be slow for large lists.

Are there any nicer and/or faster alternatives?

Comment: Sorry, it is not at all clear to me what you try to achieve. Would you please give a concrete example?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher 
I want to make the third code block based on the info given in the second code block. The code following “One possible solution...” does what I want, but it’s slow.

Comment: Uuuh... Do you really want to have such a side effect in a _pure_ function? Yes, _Mathematica_ allows you to do that by I would not consider it programming practice.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you need this for a specific purpose (working with the `StateData` internals) such that it *must* be a pure function like this.

Comment: As @b3m2a1 alludes to, I do have a specific reason to achieve what I asked for.  Maybe there's an easier way, but I thought it would be better to ask this question on its own rather than mixed in with that complicated project.  Anyhow, I'll link to the Q&A that motivates this question as soon as I write it up.

Comment: As a stop-gap, here's where you can see the desired function arise: ``First@ Last@ First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y'[t] == x[t], x'[t] == -y[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]]@"NumericalFunction"``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly this:

```
mon = Unique[NDSolve`Monitor];
mons = Table[Unique[mon], {3}];
vars = {t, x, y};

Block[{Set, Unset, CompoundExpression},
   With[{code = CompoundExpression @@ Join[
        Unset /@ #3,
        MapThread[
         Set,
         {Prepend[Through[Rest[#3][First[#3]]], First[#3]], #2}],
        {#1}
        ]},
    Function @@ {{#1}, 
      Function @@ Hold[#2, Internal`InheritedBlock[#3, code]]}
    ]] &[mon, mons, vars]

(*
  Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$234166}, 
   Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$234166$234167, 
     NDSolve`Monitor$234166$234168, NDSolve`Monitor$234166$234169},
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{t, x, y},
     t =.;
     x =.;
     y =.;
     t = NDSolve`Monitor$234166$234167; 
     x[t] = NDSolve`Monitor$234166$234168; 
     y[t] = NDSolve`Monitor$234166$234169;
     NDSolve`Monitor$234166
    ]]]
*)
```

*Update:*
This avoids blocking system functions. It shouldn't be a problem above because of the limited scope of the `Block[]` and the fact that the arguments `mon, mons, vars` are all evaluated before injected; but maybe it seems safer the following way.

```
With[{code = Join[
      Hold[#1, #2, #3],    (* first args of Function and InheritedBlock *)
      Unset /@ Hold @@ #3, (* beginning of body *)
      Set @@@ Hold @@ Transpose@
         {Prepend[Through[Rest[#3][First[#3]]], First[#3]], #2},
      Hold[#1]
      ]},
   Replace[code, Hold[m1_, m2_, v_, body__] :>
     Function[{m1}, Function[m2,
       Internal`InheritedBlock[v, CompoundExpression[body]]]]]
   ] &[mon, mons, vars] 

(*  same output as above  *)
```

Comment: Also ``Block[{Set, Unset, CompoundExpression},
 Function[#1, Function[#2, Internal`InheritedBlock[#3, #4]]] &[
  mon, mons, vars,
  CompoundExpression @@ Join[
    Unset /@ vars,
    MapThread[Set, {Prepend[Through[Rest[vars]@First[vars]], First[vars]], mons}],
    {mon}]
  ]
 ]``

Comment: Wow, just the kind of answer I was hoping for.  One trivial point - outer Function needs its first arguments as a list, but even I can figure out that tweak.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks.  I thought `Function[x,...]` and `Function[{x},...]` were the same, but maybe it matters to `NDSolve` internals?  Anyway, updated so that the code can be simply copied.

Comment: Both this answer and @kglr's deserve acceptance for their elegance -- thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
ClearAll[makeArgs, makeFunc]
makeArgs[m_, ms_, v_] := {{m}, ms, Inactive[Internal`InheritedBlock][v, 
    Inactive[CompoundExpression] @@ Flatten[
     {Inactive[Unset] /@ v, Inactive[Set][ v[[1]], ms[[1]]], 
       Inactivate[Thread[Through[Rest[v] @ First[v]] = Rest[ms]], Set], m}]]};

makeFunc = Function[#, Evaluate @ Activate @ Function[#2, #3]] & @@ makeArgs[##] &;

makeFunc[mon, mons, vars]
```

> `` Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$30945}, 
>    Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$30945$30952, NDSolve`Monitor$30945$30953, 
>      NDSolve`Monitor$30945$30954}, 
>       Internal`InheritedBlock[{t, x, y},
>         t =.; x =.; y =.; 
>         t = NDSolve`Monitor$30945$30952; 
>         x[t] = NDSolve`Monitor$30945$30953; 
>         y[t] = NDSolve`Monitor$30945$30954; 
>         NDSolve`Monitor$30945]]] ``

Comment: +1 In my opinion, `Inactive`/`Activate` are purpose-built for this task.

Comment: Nice, lots of techniques to learn from here.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than try to figure out what your detailed intentions are, let me just give a simple example. This kind of thing is easy with `Function` because it holds its arguments until it is applied. You may thus reach into a `Function` and perform arbitrary replacements. There is no need to clumsily edit text. Here, I define `powerN` as a prototype, and do replacements:

```
powerN = Function[{x}, x^n];
power2 = powerN /. n -> 2
(* Function[{x}, x^2] *)
```

Another way is to define a constructor:

```
power[n_] := Function[{x}, x^n]
power[2]
(* Function[{x$}, x$^2] *)
```

Comment: I think injecting the variable bits into the ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` is more my problem, but thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason why this won't work?

```
doopDoopDoop~SetAttributes~HoldAll;
doopDoopDoop[
  {mon_Symbol, mons : {__Symbol}, vars : {__Symbol}, t_Symbol},
  body1_,
  body2_
  ] :=
 Function[{mon},
  Function[mons,
   Internal`InheritedBlock[vars,
    vars[[1]] =.;
    vars[[2]] =.;
    body1;
    vars[[-1]] =.;
    vars[[1]] vars = mons[[1]] mons;
    vars[[2]][t] = mons[[2]];
    body2;
    vars[[-1]][t] = mons[[-1]];
    mon
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Then:

```
doopDoopDoop[
 {a, {b, c}, {d, e}, t},
 1,
 2
 ]

Function[{a}, 
 Function[{b, c}, 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{d, e}, ({d, e}[[1]]) =.; ({d, e}[[2]]) =.; 
   1; ({d, e}[[-1]]) =.; {d, e}[[1]] {d, e} = {b, c}[[1]] {b, c}; {d, e}[[2]][
     t] = {b, c}[[2]]; 2; {d, e}[[-1]][t] = {b, c}[[-1]]; a]]]
```

The annoying thing will be the parameter injection if you have `mons` stored as a list. In this case I'm going to assume you have each variable wrapped in `Hold`, because that makes it a bit more subtle. The way we'll prep the parameter list is then:

```
depVar = Hold@a;
mons = Thread@Hold@{b, c};
vars = Thread@Hold@{d, e};
timeVar = Hold@t;

paramList =
 Thread[{depVar, Thread[mons, Hold], Thread[vars, Hold], timeVar}, Hold]

Hold[{a, {b, c}, {d, e}, t}]
```

Then we inject it like:

```
Replace[
 paramList,
 Hold[pars_] :>
  doopDoopDoop[
   pars,
   1,
   2
   ]
 ]

Function[{a}, 
 Function[{b, c}, 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{d, e}, ({d, e}[[1]]) =.; ({d, e}[[2]]) =.; 
   1; ({d, e}[[-1]]) =.; {d, e}[[1]] {d, e} = {b, c}[[1]] {b, c}; {d, e}[[2]][
     t] = {b, c}[[2]]; 2; {d, e}[[-1]][t] = {b, c}[[-1]]; a]]]
```

In general, the final thing you'll want to do with an injection is wrap it in a `Replace` to inject the contents of the `Hold` or provide a function with `DownValues` that does the injection, e.g.:

```
doopDoopDoopHold~SetAttributes~HoldRest;
doopDoopDoopHold[
   Hold[pars : {mon_Symbol, mons : {__Symbol}, vars : {__Symbol}, t_Symbol}],
   body1_,
   body2_
   ] :=
  doopDoopDoop[pars, body1, body2];

doopDoopDoopHold[paramList, 1, 2]

Function[{a}, 
 Function[{b, c}, 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{d, e}, ({d, e}[[1]]) =.; ({d, e}[[2]]) =.; 
   1; ({d, e}[[-1]]) =.; {d, e}[[1]] {d, e} = {b, c}[[1]] {b, c}; {d, e}[[2]][
     t] = {b, c}[[2]]; 2; {d, e}[[-1]][t] = {b, c}[[-1]]; a]]]
```